# Excel: list of names

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns of data – first name, last name. I want to add a comma after the last name, then consolidate the two columns so that the first name comes after the last name, i.e. after the comma.

Comment: If your names are currently in cols A and B, an answer that meets the description in the question would be: fill col C cells with a comma, then drag col A to the right of col C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in Excel is to create a third column, and use the CONCATENATE formula. Assuming the first name is in cell A2, and the last name is in cell B2, paste this into column C2:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2, ", ", A2)
```

Then copy cell C2, and paste it down the rest of the column.

Comment: Thats perfect, but the list has a few hundred names. Is there a more automated way to apply the formula?

Comment: Sounds like you're making pretty broad assumptions. I didn't even know this would require code. I spent a good amount of time in other places online trying to find a solution. A simple "yes, this can be done in Excel but requires custom code" would've been enough, because I didn't know if there was a more simple way to do it. So, yeah thanks for the help.

Comment: @alxmntrvl, you can paste the same formula in several cells at once: 1) After having the formula in the first cell, C2, copy that cell. 2) Click cell C3, then scroll down to the bottom, and shift-click the last cell in column C. This will select all of the cells in that column that need the formula. 3) Paste. This will paste the same formula all the way down, adapted for each row.